# react and paypal-rest-sdk: how to pass data from the payment page back to the application

Tags: node.js, reactjs, paypal, axios

I have a React single page application that allows users to purchase saved products through paypal-rest-sdk (docs [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/paypal-rest-sdk)). The way I want this to work is to have the logged in user be able to order a product if it is in stock. The user inputs how many products they want, and then an order containing the product and amount is created and stored as "Created". The user is then redirected to the Paypal purchase page where they confirm or cancel the payment. After confirming the previously created order is found again and is set to "Completed" with a transaction created to store the Paypal payment information. Currently I can make a successful payment, order, and transaction in a sandbox environment.

My problem right now is that the redirect I use to get to and from the Paypal payment page is resulting in my app forgetting the logged in user so I'm unable to get the user's "Created" order after a successful payment. I have to use window.location in my postOrder() function or else I get a Cross Reference Error, as explained in a user's answer to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60859295/cross-origin-request-blocked-when-requesting-paypal-sandbox-but-a-different-loca). I need the user to be remembered or else any order labeled "Created" could be grabbed and set to "Completed", needless to say this will cause massive problems in my app. How should I go about this problem, or should I just try another approach?

Frontend Logic:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { useID, useUserName, useAdmin } from "../../context/auth";
import { Button, Accordion, Card, ListGroup, Form, Col } from "react-bootstrap";
import axios from "axios";

function ProductDetails(props) {
    const [isError, setIsError] = useState(false);
    const [id, setID] = useState("");
    const [name, setName] = useState("");
    const [description, setDescription] = useState("");
    const [price, setPrice] = useState(0);
    const [stock, setStock] = useState(0);
    const [amount, setAmount] = useState(0);
    const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);
    const { IDTokens } = useID();
    const { userNameTokens } = useUserName();
    const { adminTokens } = useAdmin();

    const Message = props => (
        <Card>
            <Card.Body>
                <Card.Title>
                    {props.message.owner.username === "(User removed)" ? (
                        <span>{props.message.owner.username}</span>
                    ) : (
                        <Link to={`/users/${props.message.owner.id}`}>{props.message.owner.username}</Link>                        
                    )}
                </Card.Title>
                <Card.Text>
                    {props.message.content}
                </Card.Text>
                {IDTokens === props.message.owner.id || adminTokens ? (
                    <span>
                        <Link  to={`/products/list/${id}/messages/${props.message._id}/edit/`} style={{ marginRight: 10, marginLeft: 10 }}>
                            Edit
                        </Link>
                        <Link to={`/products/list/${id}/messages/${props.message._id}/delete/`}>Delete</Link>
                    </span>
                ) : (
                    <span></span>
                )}
            </Card.Body>
        </Card>
    )

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get(`http://localhost:4000/products/${props.match.params.id}`)
        .then(res => {
            setID(res.data.product._id);
            setName(res.data.product.name);
            setDescription(res.data.product.description);
            setPrice(res.data.product.price);
            setStock(res.data.product.stock);
            setMessages(res.data.messages);
        }).catch(function(err) {
            setIsError(true);
        })
    }, [props, IDTokens]);

    function messageList() {
        return messages.map(function(currentMessage, i) {
            return <Message message={currentMessage} key={i} />;
        })
    }

    function postOrder() {
        if(amount <= stock) {
            let productInfo = {
                id,
                name,
                description,
                price,
                amount
            };

            let orderInfo = {
                owner: {
                    id: IDTokens,
                    username: userNameTokens
                },
                status: "Created"
            };

            axios.post("http://localhost:4000/orders/pay",
                {productInfo, orderInfo}
            ).then((res) => {
                if(res.status === 200) {
                    window.location = res.data.forwardLink;
                } else {
                    setIsError(true);
                }
            }).catch((err) => {
                setIsError(true);
            })
        }
    }

    return (
        <div className="text-center">
            <h2>Products Details</h2>
            <Accordion>
                <Card>
                    <Card.Header>
                        <Accordion.Toggle as={Button} variant="link" eventKey="0">
                            Product Info
                        </Accordion.Toggle>
                    </Card.Header>
                    <Accordion.Collapse eventKey="0">
                        <Card.Body>
                            <ListGroup>
                                <ListGroup.Item>Name: {name}</ListGroup.Item>
                                <ListGroup.Item>Description: {description}</ListGroup.Item>
                                <ListGroup.Item>Price: ${price.toFixed(2)}</ListGroup.Item>
                                <ListGroup.Item>Stock: {stock}</ListGroup.Item>
                            </ListGroup>
                            {stock > 0 && IDTokens ? (
                                <Form>
                                    <h2>Order This Product</h2>
                                    <Form.Row>
                                        <Form.Group as={Col} sm={{ span: 6, offset: 3 }}>
                                            <Form.Label htmlFor="formAmount">Amount</Form.Label>
                                            <Form.Control
                                                        controlid="formAmount"
                                                        type="number"
                                                        min="1"
                                                        max="5"
                                                        step="1"
                                                        onChange={e => {
                                                            setAmount(e.target.value);
                                                        }}
                                                        placeholder="Enter amount to order (max 5)"
                                                        />
                                        </Form.Group>
                                    </Form.Row>
                                    <Button onClick={postOrder} variant="success">Order Now</Button>
                                    { isError &&<p>Something went wrong with making the order!</p> }
                                </Form>
                            ) : (
                                "Cannot order, currently out of stock or user is not currently logged in"
                            )}
                        </Card.Body>
                    </Accordion.Collapse>
                </Card>
            </Accordion>
            <Link to={`/products/list/${id}/messages/new`}>Questions or Comments Regarding this Product? Leave a Message.</Link>
            <h3>Messages: </h3>
            {messages.length > 0 ? (
                messageList()
            ) : (
                <p>(No messages)</p>
            )}
            { isError &&<p>Something went wrong with getting the product!</p> }
        </div>
    )
}

export default ProductDetails;
```

Backend Logic:

```
const express = require("express"),
router = express.Router(),
paypal = require("paypal-rest-sdk"),
Order = require("../database/models/order"),
Transaction = require("../database/models/transaction");

// Order pay logic route
router.post("/pay", function(req, res) {
    const productInfo = req.body.productInfo;

    const create_payment_json = {
        "intent": "sale",
        "payer": {
            "payment_method": "paypal"
        },
        "redirect_urls": {
            "return_url": "http://localhost:4000/orders/success",
            "cancel_url": "http://localhost:4000/orders/cancel"
        },
        "transactions": [{
            "item_list": {
                "items": [{
                    "name": productInfo.name,
                    "sku": "001",
                    "price": productInfo.price,
                    "currency": "USD",
                    "quantity": productInfo.amount
                }]
            },
            "amount": {
                "currency": "USD",
                "total": productInfo.price * productInfo.amount
            },
            "description": productInfo.description
        }]
    };

    paypal.payment.create(create_payment_json, function(err, payment) {
        if(err) {
            console.log(err.message);
        } else {
            let order = new Order(req.body.orderInfo);
            order.product = {
                _id: productInfo.id,
                name: productInfo.name,
                description: productInfo.description,
                price: productInfo.price,
                amount: productInfo.amount
            }
            order.total = productInfo.price * productInfo.amount;
            order.save().then(order => {
                console.log(`Order saved successfully! Created order details: ${order}`);
            }).catch(err => {
                console.log("Order create error: ", err.message);
            });

            for(let i = 0; i < payment.links.length; i++) {
              if(payment.links[i].rel === "approval_url") {
                  res.status(200).json({forwardLink: payment.links[i].href});
              } else {
                  console.log("approval_url not found");
              }
            }
        }
      });
});

router.get("/success", function(req, res) {
    const payerId = req.query.PayerID;
    const paymentId = req.query.paymentId;

    Order.findOneAndUpdate({ "owner.id": req.user, status: "Created" }).then((order) => {
        order.status = "Completed";

        const execute_payment_json = {
            "payer_id": payerId,
            "transactions": [{
                "amount": {
                    "currency": "USD",
                    "total": order.total
                }
            }]
        };

        paypal.payment.execute(paymentId, execute_payment_json, function(err, payment) {
            if(err) {
                console.log("paypal.payment.execute error: ", err.response);
            } else {
                let transaction = new Transaction();
                transaction.details = JSON.stringify(payment);
                order.transaction = transaction;
                order.save().then(order => {
                    transaction.save().then(transaction => {
                        res.status(200).json(`Payment accepted! Order details: ${order}`);
                    }).catch(err => {
                        console.log("Transaction create error: ", err.message);
                    });
                }).catch(err => {
                    console.log("Order complete error: ", err.message);
                });
            }
        });
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log("Payment error: ", err.message);
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Order Model:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose"),
Schema = mongoose.Schema;

let orderSchema = new Schema({
    product: {
        _id: {
            type: String
        },
        name: {
            type: String
        },
        description: {
            type: String
        },
        price: {
            type: Number
        },
        amount: {
            type: Number
        }
    },
    total: {
        type: Number
    },
    status: { // Created or Completed
        type: String
    },
    transaction: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Transaction"
    },
    owner: {
        id: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User"},
        username: String
    },
    createdAt: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now()
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Order", orderSchema);
```

Transaction Model:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose"),
Schema = mongoose.Schema;

let transactionSchema = new Schema({
    details: [],
    createdAt: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now()
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Transaction", transactionSchema);
```

Answer (score 1):

Why are you redirecting to and from PayPal?

The best solution is to switch to this front-end pattern, and not redirect at all: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

Those fetch "/demo/...." need to be replaced with routes on your server to create the order and return an OrderID, and capture an OrderID, respectively.

The benefit here is your site remains open in the background, providing an "in-context" checkout experience.

---

If you want to see what the experience looks like, try the client-side-JS-only version which does not depend on working fetch routes to those '/demo/...' placeholders: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/client